# Error: transition superseded

Tags: node.js, angular-fullstack

I was developing my project and at some point I got this error:

```
Error: transition superseded
Traza de la pila:
$get@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:38916:38
invoke@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:5167:17
createInjector/protoInstanceInjector<@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:4959:21
getService@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:5108:33
[9]/<@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:39703:8
invoke@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:5167:17
createInjector/<@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:4969:46
forEach@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:537:12
createInjector@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:4969:4
doBootstrap@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:2076:21
bootstrap@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:2097:13
@http://localhost:3000/app.bundle.js:110:4
trigger@http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:3595:6
 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

Everything seems working, so at the begining I didn't mind about it. But the error message is still there and it's becoming annoying. When the page is loaded for the first time it isn't shown, however, it appears when I navigate between different views.

I was searching about it, and people talk about ui-router. Somehow, I'm a newbie developping with Angular-Fullstack generator (Yeoman) and don't know where should I look to solve the error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Bumping the angular-ui-router to 0.4.2 and the error resolved itself.

> https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel/pull/203